# R.font не видит в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Я создал папку font в папке res:
New->Android Resource Directory

Resource type выбрал font, Directory name - тоже font.
[image: скриншот из android studio]

Папка font успешно создалась в папке res. Я в неё поместил штрифты.

Но почему-то, когда в коде я пишу R.font., то font мне подчёркивает красным как ошибку, так как не видит это папку в R.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему? Нужно как-то самому ссылку на эту папку в R добавить? Вообще похоже как глюк какой-то в android studio. Кстати, у меня стабильная версия

Comment: попробуйте пересобрать проект чтобы файлы проиндексировались

Comment: пробовал сделать clean project и rebuild, не помогло

Comment: а если перезагрузиться с очисткой кэша что будет?

Comment: Как оказалось, всё очень просто. Скаченный с google fonts штрифт нужно переименовать в нижний регистр, убрать знаки "-". И тогда папка стала определяться.

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, всё очень просто. Скаченный с google fonts штрифт нужно переименовать в нижний регистр, убрать знаки "-". И тогда папка стала определяться.